# Retrieval of data in HashSet

Tags: java, collections, set, hashset

I want to know that in which manner, the data is retrieve in HashSet
I have inserted data in different order and output data is in another order.
Can someone please tell the logic behind this?

Code is like this :-

```
    class Test 
    { 
        public static void main(String[]args) 
        { 
            HashSet<String> h = new HashSet<String>(); 

            // Adding elements into HashSet using add() 
            h.add("India"); 
            h.add("Australia"); 
            h.add("South Africa"); 
            System.out.println(h); 
        }
}
```

Output:- [South Africa, Australia, India]

Comment: Use `Set<String>set = new LinkedHashSet<String>()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Javadoc of HashSet

> It makes no guarantees as to the
>     iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the
>     order will remain constant over time.

Answer (score 0):

HashSet works same as HashMap with Value. Moreover It internally uses HashMap With value constant Object called "PRESENT". By doing this HashSet guarantee uniqueness but not order It locate the set elements similarly as what Hashmap do.

You can see the implementation of HashSet on internet.

Comment: That might be the case for some implementations, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: Can you please suggest some cases ?

Comment: It's not guaranteed, meaning it may not be the case in all implementations. Don't make assertions where the documentation explicitly states those assertions are false. In this specific case, the implementation looks to be a LIFO queue, rather than a hash based collection.

Answer (score 0):

As said, the ordering of elements in a HashSet is not guaranteed to be anything, nor to be constant over time.

This is due to the nature of the underlying data structure.

In your case, it looks like the Strings were stored in a LIFO queue, but another implementation of HashSet may well do things differently (and even this one might as more items get inserted, start to behave differently).

Answer (score 0):

As per the above, please see the Javadoc for HashSets - the order is not guaranteed. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the LinkedHashSet if you want it to maintain the order of elements.